# JS Codecademy exercise NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE:

Tags: javascript

I am a coding newbie. I am learning JS on Codecademy and I keep getting this error : `NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE`. What am I doing wrong in the following code?

```
prompt ("Are you ready to play"); 
confirm ("I am ready to play!"); 
var age = prompt("What's your age"); 
if("age" <= 12) {     
  console.log("Play at your own risk"); 
} else {     
  console.log("Play on!"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`age` is a variable, not a string, there is no need for quotes:

```
prompt ("Are you ready to play"); 
confirm ("I am ready to play!"); 
var age = prompt("What's your age"); 
if(age <= 12) {     
  console.log("Play at your own risk"); 
} else {     
  console.log("Play on!"); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use age without the quotes, as you are referencing a *variable*, not a *string*

```
if (age <= 12)
```

"age" with quotes in javascript means the literal word (or 'string') age, and so comparing "age" with 12 won't get the the result you expected

age without quotes in javascript means whatever value is associated to the variable `age`, in this case, whatever the user entered into the `prompt()`

Comment: `you cannot compare "age" to 12` -> that is not correct, you can compare them. What you can't, is compare them and expect to get `true`.